# How to add installed program to command prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a problem with adding already installed program as available command in windows cmd. For example I installed new text Geany and want to open text file using this command:

```
geany myfile.txt
```

I looked over the internet but couldn't find solution for this. I see that windows will execute programs that are added to PATHS like C:/Windows or C:/Windows/System32. I tried adding Shortcut to geany executable but this doesn't work, it doesn't execute shortcuts

Any help on this appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add `geany.exe` to the path in Windows.

You can get the full path to `geany.exe` by right clicking the shortcut and selecting the entire Target

- right click my computer
- click Properties
- click Advanced System Settings
- click Environment Variables
- In the bottom pane find `Path`, select it and click Edit
- after the last `;`, add the full path to the *folder* containing geany.exe  (in this case you must add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\bin\`, also note the `\` at the end)

Now you should be able to launch `geany` from the command line, or from Start\Run

PS: Make sure to restart the CMD application before trying it out. You will need to open a new CMD window after the changes have been made.

Comment: thanks Keltari, i have done this but still doesn't work. I will re-start computer and see if that helps

Comment: be sure to quote the string if their are spaces in the path

Comment: One thing to add to this: you 'might' need to reboot the computer or at the very least log off, then on again for the new path variable to be updated (I say 'might' because experience has shown that sometimes the new path variable doesn't get recognized until a login/reboot) ... side note: i have a C:\custom_cmds\ that is in my path variable that I then just drop shortcut's (named the same as the application) into. This has an added advantage of never needing to modify PATH again or messing with config files of certain programs (just as an anecdote)

Comment: i don't know guys I think I did this correctly, even after re-start still doesn't work, it says "geany.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command...., i tried with both geany and geany.exe

Comment: then you missed a step or put the path in wrong.  thats all there is to it.  double check everything.

Comment: yes sorry :) works fine now; my bad. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just encountered the same issue. Everything the above poster said is true except you should add the entire bin folder to your PATH variable. For me it was C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\bin

Comment: This worked for me when I restarted the command line application. Thanks for sharing the great info.

Comment: Can I use either "User variables" or "System Variables" when I set the path?

Comment: (1) @RasmusLarsen: "User variables" apply to your account only; "System Variables" apply to all users. (2) You do not need to include a ````\```` at the end of the names of folders.  (3) In the Environment Variables window, you do not use quotes — not even for folder names that contain spaces.